# Opening text files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment which involves extracting some information from a file. However, I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```
def main():
    print("Hello, this program will create a")
    print("bar graph showing the sales")
    print("\n\nSales Bar Graph")
    INFILE = open("sales.txt", "r")
    store1, store2, store3, store4, store5 = (INFILE.read()).split(", ")
    print(store1)
```

When I try to run this program, nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure the path to the file is correct?
Try to use the full path to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Nothing happens" isn't technically true: your program defines a function called `main`. However, you never call that function, so its contents are never executed. Add a call to this function after defining it.

```
def main():
    ...

main()
```

Comment: Haha I was stupid, but I called main and got an error:  ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: the contents of the sales.txt file are 781, 904, 1105, 564, 789

Comment: Never mind, that had somehting to do with an earlier part of the program

Comment: I was just going to say that it worked fine on my end. :) Don't forget to do `INFILE.close()` when you're done with the file, or, better yet, use the [`with` construct](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).